# PHP или Node.js

Tags: node.js, php, javascript

Собираюсь конкретно углубиться в один из данных серверных ЯП: 
-PHP 
-Node.js

Во всех тестах что я видел, Node.js **опережает в 2 а то и в 5** раз PHP.
Все ли возможности **PHP, поддерживает Node.js?** 
Интересно узнать ваше мнение,очень интересно, какой ЯП сложней, **в будущем** имеет приоритет и т.д.
**Спасибо** за ответы, если не сложно.

Comment: Изучайте Зефир, по моему лучший язык

Comment: для "конкретно углубится" нужно минимум лет 10.  Что будет через 10 лет? Большой вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Выбор языка стоять не должен никогда: любой язык изучается за минимальный промежуток времени, если имеешь адекватные знания о технологиях и опыт их практического применения. В остальном же, на сегодняшний день учиться проще на PHP - спрос больше конкуренции, можно учиться на реальных задачах и получать за это какие-то деньги. Про node.js такого пока сказать нельзя - даже на устаревший в рамках веба PERL рыночный спрос выше.

Answer (score 3):

> Во всех тестах что я видел, Node.js опережает в 2 а то и в 5 раз PHP.

Опережает в чем? В скорости? А если опережает в скорости выполнения, но проигрывает в скорости разработки? Можно ведь и на сишке веб-приложения писать.

> Все ли возможности PHP, поддерживает Node.js?

Примерно тот же вопрос. Есть ли в ноде аналог пакетов symfony? Есть ли уже готовое решение для эмуляции виртуальной файловой системы? Широкие ли возможности у основного фреймворка тестирования?

Главное различие там в подходе программирования. Нода будет вся такая из себя асинхронная и на коллбэках, а пых весь такой.

Однопоточный и тоже на анонимных функциях, если ларавель какой-нибудь. Я вот не могу в коллбэки, и поэтому туда не суюсь. Что касательно скорости - к следующей версии PHP у него будет почти полностью переписанный движок, скорость скакнет, будете пересаживаться, если он на синтетике обгонит node.js? Ну и по сложности алгоритмов 2-5 раза - это околонулевая разница.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуем по порядку.

> Собираюсь конкретно углубиться в один из данных серверных ЯП: 
>   -PHP 
>   -Node.js

**PHP** - это язык программирования.

- РНР ориентирован на работу в веб-приложениях (сайты)
- РНР однопоточный, "рожден что-бы умирать". т.е. получил данные от браузера, обработал, выдал результат, завершился. Сколько у вас запросов, столько запустится приложений
- синхронный (в большинстве случаев) - любое действие "останавливает" вашу программу, пока это дейтсвие не завершится
- stateless - все переменные и контексты сохраняются в пределах одного запроса
- установлен на всех хостингах

**NodeJs** - это среда выполнения, использующая язык **JavaScript**

- Современный, развивающиеся среда и язык. 2015-09-08 вышла новая мажорная версия ноды
- имеет широкую область применения: микрокомпьютеры, микроконтроллеры, веб приложения, игровые сервера и  многое другое.
- приложение ноды обычно запускается один раз и оно обслуживает все запросы. Все контексты и переменные постоянно доступны в приложении между запросами.
- асинхронный (в больштнстве случаев) - многие тяжелые действия (как подключение к базе данных) не останавливают выполнение основной программы, а по окончании обработки, вызывают колбек-процедуру с передачей результатов
- требует "отдельный" сервер (почти нет хостингов NodeJs)

> Во всех тестах что я видел, Node.js опережает в 2 а то и в 5 раз PHP.

По скорости выполнения однотипного кода Node скорее всего выигрывает. В том числе за счет возможности выполнять код параллельно на нескольких процессорах.

> Все ли возможности PHP, поддерживает Node.js?

Ответ скорее ДА и даже больше возможностей

> Интересно узнать ваше мнение,очень интересно, какой ЯП сложней, в будущем имеет приоритет и т.д.

Возращаясь к началу, мы рассматриваем два языка: PHP & JavaScript

РНР используется в основном только для разработки сайтов.

JS имеет более широкую область применения. ЯС используется в том числе и в браузерах. ЯС входит в пятерку самых популярных языков программирования.

Изучение языка зависит от того, какую задачу Вы хотите решать.

**Изучайте оба**, синтаксически они очень похожи.

вот например маленький абстрактный код, который будет работать и на РНР и ноде

```
$i = 1;
for($j=0;$j<1000;$j++) {
    $i *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Семантически же язык гораздо ближе к Self, Smalltalk или даже Лиспу.

Comment: В Apache mod_php и FastCGI PHP скрипт не умирает после ответа.